# Is there a way to find ignite's table last update time?

Tags: ignite

Is there a way to find ignite's table last update time?
Better using a SQL query.

Like:

```
SELECT LAST_UPDATE_TIME FROM SYS.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME="MY_TABLE_NAME"
```

Comment: I don't think that Apache Ignite tracks it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the SQL_QUERIES_HISTORY system view to check for queries that performed an update on a particular table: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring-metrics/system-views#sql_queries_history

Comment: I took a look to this history but didn't see that query that had updated the table. I don't know the exact politic they have to track queries, but seems it's not reliable.